# how to change date related to another date input without select event in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

> i have two inputs #date and #date2 and i was in the edit page..so date
>   come from database . i want if someone click in #date2 input the popup
>   date picker window hide all dates before #date input.how to do this without use select event in the first input?

example : input date 08/04//2014
          input date2 should be 08/04/2014

```
  //// stat date
     $("#date").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                    $("#date2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });

/// end date
            $("#date2").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                 minDate: // first input date value will be here //

            });
```

Comment: you said date a lot, kinda confusing!

Comment: [look at datepicker example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

Comment: no all examples using select event,i don't want this and i don't want any event to change #date2 input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be helpful for you! Try this

```
$("#date2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: $('#date').val(),
    onSelect:function(date){
        var start_date = new Date($('#date').val());
        var end_date = new Date(date);
        if(start_date > end_date ){
            alert('date start should be less than date end');
            $(this).val('');
            //$('#date').val(''); // add if you want
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it is good but is this anyway to hide all dates before input #date

Comment: Use beforeShow: function(){//you operations}, For more info http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/